# Each group has the not common template for the same one listview in winjs?

Tags: listview, winjs

the listview has two groups
and the each group has not the same template
how can do this ??
Please help me !!

Answer (score 0):

you should make an id for every `div` which represent a group.Then in the `CSS` style the id as you want.

try to check the same question here

[WinJS Multicolumn Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463181/winjs-multicolumn-listview)